# Saving <file.php>: Running 'phpcbf' Formatter (configure)

Tags: wordpress, visual-studio-code, coding-style

I've recently set up WP coding standards in VSCode by following https://www.edmundcwm.com/setting-up-wordpress-coding-standards-in-vs-code/.

With this setup files aren't getting saved and shows this message at the bottom right:

> Saving ‘plugin.php’: Running ‘phpcbf’ Formatter (configure).

The only way to save is to press Cancel when this appears.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Please use which phpcs & which phpcbf to find the paths.

which phpcs
e.g. "C:\Users{Your username}\AppData\Roaming\Composer\Vendor\bin\phpcs

which phpcbf
e.g. C:\Users{Your username}\AppData\Roaming\Composer\Vendor\bin\phpcbf

once you find the paths to the executables, open your vscode json settings and add double check that the executable settings for phpcs & phpcbf match the paths.

Examples:

"phpcs.executablePath": "C:\Users\{Your username}\AppData\Roaming\Composer\Vendor\bin\phpcs.bat",

"phpcbf.executablePath": "C:\Users\{Your username}\AppData\Roaming\Composer\Vendor\bin\phpcbf.bat",

Comment: Consider using system variable userprofile: %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\Vendor\bin...

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is pretty widespread despite the lack of answers in this thread. Setting the paths as above does not fix things. For me, this happens when saving a file and there is nothing for the formatter to fix.

There is an [open pull request](https://github.com/soderlind/vscode-phpcbf/pull/41/commits/f6c54d6efd6948c3e75ee9bbce00fb70202e1bac) for this issue that has been open for over a year now.

[A fork of the project](https://github.com/simone-baldini/vscode-phpcbf) has popped up that specifically fixes this issue. Look for phpcbf in VSCode and find the one by Simone Baldini.

Try installing that to see if it resolves the problem.